# FirebaseCrashlytics won't compile for iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to integrate FirebaseCrashlytics to replace Fabric / Crashlytics.
So far, I've followed the steps in the docs and it all seems to be working on a device. I'm able to simulate crashes and see the crashes in firebase. The issue is when I'm trying to build for the simulator, it won't compile. Does anyone know how to get around this?

I'm using Xcode 11.5
Installing through cocoapods via this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk

[image: Showing errors for Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64]

Comment: Which docs are you following and how are you installing?  The environment is missing linking the GoogleUtilities library.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien  I'm installing through Cocoapods
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
The versions are:
Firebase (6.26.0)
FirebaseAnalytics (6.6.0)
FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.5.0)
FirebaseCore (6.7.2)
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.3.0)
FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
FirebaseCrashlytics (4.1.1)
FirebaseInstallations (1.3.0)
GoogleAppMeasurement (6.6.0)
GoogleDataTransport (6.2.1)
GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (3.1.0)
GoogleUtilities (6.6.0)
PromisesObjC (1.2.9)
nanopb (1.30905.0)

The doc:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk

Answer (score 0):

So, I've tried integrating via Carthage instead, and got the same result. I did notice that those errors only appear when I try to use

`Crashlytics.crashlytics().setUserID(userIdentifier)`

or some `Crashlytics.crashlytics()` function calls.

I did get the program to compile successfully and launching on the simulator via #if NDEBUG directives. So basically, whenever I needed to make use of Crashlytics.crashlytics(), I would put it inside #if NDEBUG and it works.

For example:

```
#if NDEBUG
Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCustomValue("someValue", forKey: "someKey")
#endif
```